# How define user how much time stay at site online in mvc 4 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I use my custom user table in my application. I need to calculate that, how much time user is online in a day. How can I do this? any ideas please.

I think so that,  when application start, I should save that datetime and when user exits from application, to save that datetime and find their's difference. I know `Application_Start` method, but dont find any method that works on closing application.

Comment: Session , not application

Comment: there is `Application_End` also...but this is upto session...

Comment: Unless your application makes periodic calls to the server, then your session may time-out before the user is done.